# what is the best way to migrate configuration data from local environment to production magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have development environment of magento 2.4.1 up and running on my local system. When ever I do any changes in the configuration or created new CMS page,block etc on my local environment I want to do migrate it on production. To do this,Kindly suggest the best way?

Currently I am doing it by manually.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 does not offer this in an easy way, as far as I know. However, you can use the [settings migration](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/migration/migration-migrate-settings.html) and [data migration](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/migration/migration-migrate-data.html) tools, magento offers.
Be aware that if you are testing something on your local environment and don't change it back, the migration tools might migrate that to your production environment.
I never worked with these myself, so you'll have to figure out how to use those according to your needs.